# How do I control a webpage with an arduino?

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino I want to set up with a button, to put a signal through an input pin, that will turn a light on or off on an external website (Not hosted on the Ethernet shield). I have been looking through online documentation, but the only thing I can find is something about thermometer readings. Some relevant info, I have an Arduino Uno with an Ethernet shield. I have made this work to turn the Arduino on or off using the site, I am trying to do this in the other direction now. I used a php script to control Arduino from the page, I can provide my code if anyone wants.

Could anyone offer me any advice or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a web page from PHP, fully loaded in your browser window.  Now there is no more server-side action until something happens on the client side (form submit, refresh, click link to a new page, etc.)

What I think you should be looking into is ajax, or node.js socket transmission to display the light or whatever on the page in realtime when the device is turned on or off.

TL;DR
PHP alone is not going to suit your needs in this situation. You'll need something async.

Comment: Alright, can you suggest how I would send the information from the Arduino to the web server and how to make the page use the information? I don't know anything about ajax or node.js. Or possibly could you link a web guide on how to this?

Comment: I've never used an Arduino, nor have I used Ajax.  But I do use PHP extensively, so I know its limitations.  Maybe someone more qualified can help you further if you update your question a bit.

Comment: What sort of information should I add? I don't use stack overflow much.

Comment: I've pointed you in a vague right direction, probably AJAX will be your best bet for asynchronous updating of the web page, to turn the light off and on, on the external site, in real-time.  So now you have a narrower scope of what needs to be done.  You need to store a variable somehow on your external site, which tells if your arduino is currently on or off.  You'll probably want your ajax page to listen for a change in that value, and you'll want to somehow change that value when your arduino is turned on or off.  That seems like the functionality you're looking for to me, anyway.

Comment: If, inside your arduino code, you could somehow send GET or POST data to your web server, the web server (using ajax or node) could receive that POST data, store it in a javascript variable.  It could be a simple true/false global boolean that gets updated every time the light changes state, and sends an update.  From node, the update can be programatically broadcast to all active clients (everyone who needs to see right now whether the light is on or off). Then, each client receives the update and changes their view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I did one project 2 years back, monitoring water level using arduino+ethernet. I used PHP. The project is displaying water level on the web page, arduino measures the water level with some sensors and ethernet module will send sensor value to server. I am sending water level (sensor value) to a text file (L.txt) on the server using tank.php.

**arduino code**

```
/* put this in loop so that it reads level value and and send to the server every second*/
sprintf(buffer, "GET /tank.php?level=%d HTTP/1.0",level );
client.println(buffer);
client.println( "Host: localhost");
```

tank.php will write the level value to L.txt.

**code for tank.php**

```
<?php
$l = $_GET["level"]; 
$fileLocation= "L.txt";
$fl = fopen($fileLocation, 'w') or die("Something went wrong!"); 
fwrite($fl, $l);
fclose($fl); 
?>
```

Finally waterlevel.php for displaying. waterlevel.php reads the value from L.txt and displays water level on the web page (I used Meta tag for auto refresh every second).

**code for waterlevel.php**

```
<?php
$l = file_get_contents("L.txt");
$tanklevel=$l;
$a = 2 *(100 - $tanklevel) ;
$b = 2*$tanklevel ;
echo "<html><center>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=1>";
echo "<p align= center >";
echo "<font size= 8 >";
echo "<h1>Tank Level</h1>";
echo "<h2> $tanklevel% </h2>";
echo "</p>";
echo "<table width=200 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1>";
echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#cccccc height= $a ></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#3333aa height= $b ></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</center></html>";
?>
```